# css script opencart with php file

Tags: php, css, opencart

I try to create one CSS File with the following PHP Script:
Integrated in OpenCart to reduce http requests.

...\catalog\controller\common\css.php:

```
    class ControllerCommonCss extends Controller {
    public function index() { 

      $this->log->write('test');

      $cssFiles = array(
      "stylesheet.css",
      );

         $buffer = "";
         foreach ($cssFiles as $cssFile) {
         $buffer .= file_get_contents($cssFile);

         ...
      }
     }
    }
```

header.tpl:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="catalog/controller/common/css.php" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

The output "test" in error.log don't work. And the stylesheet don't load in the header. Can someone tell me whats wrong?

greetings

Comment: If you're extending a `controller` you should have a `route` defined for that `method index` inside that `controller` and pass to the html that `route`

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "don't work"?

Comment: The call to the php script don't work. I tried like this "<link rel="stylesheet" href="catalog/controller/index.php?route=common/css" type="text/css" media="screen">" in the header.tpl

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use an extension like NitroPack Cache which does this and a load of other stuff: 
https://docs.isenselabs.com/nitropack/minification

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **combine** your css files you can **paste** this code in your **css.php** file

↓

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
$path_to_files = '../../view/theme/default/css/'; // edit path to css directory
$files = array(
    'product-page.css',
    'stylesheet.css',
    'theme.css'
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    include($path_to_files . $file);
}
```

..

If you need to **combine & compress** them .. use this code **instead**:

↓

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/css');
ob_start("compress");

function compress($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}

$path_to_files = '../../view/theme/default/css/'; // edit path to css directory

$files = array(
    'stylesheet.css',
    'theme.css',
    'custom.css'
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    include($path_to_files . $file);
}

ob_end_flush();
```

P.S: you don't need to treat this file as an opencart controller, It's just a php file

Thanks for : https://wp-mix.com/combine-compress-css-files-php/